# Output variable from dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have an issue wen I try to output a value from a dynamic T-SQL Query inside of a stored procedure.

I try to execute the following and simply output a 1 if something was found:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @returnValue int
DECLARE @Statement nvarchar(400)
set @Statement = 'SELECT @result=''1'' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                  WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''sourceTable''
                  AND COLUMN_NAME = @columnIN
                  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo'''
exec sp_executesql @Statement, 
    N'@columnIN nvarchar(60),@result INT OUTPUT', 
    @columnIN = @column, @result=@returnValue OUTPUT    
select @returnValue
```

This currently yields `NULL`. Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Additional Information:
The column that I try to lookup is for example column1 . If I run the SQL query with `...AND CLOUMN_NAME = 'column1' ...` I get a 1 back. 
If I print the `@column` variable in the SP I get 'column1'. 
`@column` is declared as an input variable with nvarchar(60) in the SP: `PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_checkColumn] (@column nvarchar(60), @result INT OUTPUT)`

As per request the complete SP here:

```
  Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_checkColumn] (@column nvarchar(60), @result INT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @returnValue int
    DECLARE @Statement nvarchar(400)
    set @Statement = 'SELECT @result=''1'' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''t_table''
                       AND COLUMN_NAME = @columnIN
                        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo'''

    exec sp_executesql @Statement, N'@columnIN nvarchar(60),@result INT OUTPUT', @columnIN = @column, @result=@returnValue OUTPUT    
    select @returnValue      
    return @returnValue

END
```

And here's how I call the SP:

```
DECLARE fcursor CURSOR
FOR
  select FieldName 
  from t_fieldDefinition 
OPEN fcursor

Fetch next from fcursor into @field;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @tmpField = '''' + @field + ''''
  SET @field ='[' + @field  + ']' 
  set @available = 0 
  exec usp_checkColumn @tmpField,@available OUTPUT
```

If I print the [@column] variable in the usp_checkColumn I do get the correct column inside of the ''. If I copy & paste the print of this variable and insert it into the query I get a 1 back, if I run the SP I get NULL(converted to 0 as NULL is not valid for the INT variable) back.

Here's the content of the t_fieldDefinition table:

```
FieldName   ID
Source      5
column1     6
column2     7
Client      8
asd BSX     9
bsd         10
esd         11
esx         12
```

And here's the definition of the t_table table:

```
ID          bigint          Unchecked
Source      varchar(250)    Checked
column1     varchar(250)    Checked
column2     nvarchar(100)   Checked
Client      varchar(10)     Checked
asd         varchar(250)    Checked
[asd BSX]   varchar(250)    Checked
```

so that means that it should return 1 for all that are inside of the table definition and 0 for all others. Is it possible that the fields with a white space can be the issue? Although they work as well when you do it manually. It's not that I really have an option to change it but at least I would now the cause of the issue then.

Comment: What does "not ... successfully" mean? Do you get an error, the wrong value, something else? Are you sure you populated `@column` correctly? The code works fine for me.

Comment: It does return NULL, @column is an input variable of the Stored Procedure and always contains 'columnName' as I print them for troubleshooting

Comment: Then either the column wasn't found or you didn't populate `@column`.

Comment: As an addition: If I run the select statement by itself I get a 1 for all columns. The query is exactly the same

Comment: <sigh> Where do you populate `@column`? How can the query be "exactly the same"?

Comment: @nja Is this the complete query you're executing? Because in this current form the variable [@column] is not declared so the script is invalid. If [@column] is a procedure param, print the value and see what you get. Anyway, Aaron is right and either the column is missing or the string for [@column] is different than the real one.

Comment: Perhaps `@column` is declared as `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` without length, and thus is truncated to a single character. If this is the case, please add a length to the parameter definition, and [read this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: The column that I try to lookup is for example column1 . If I run the SQL query with '...AND CLOUMN_NAME = 'column1' ...' I get a 1 back. If I print the [@column] variable in the SP I get 'column1'. [@column] is declared as an input nvarchar(60) in the SP

Comment: Cool so you get downvotes if the question is not easily solved and <sigh> comments...

Comment: No, you likely get down-votes when you post an incomplete question that seems to be too localized to be useful to anyone, because you've left out some detail that is causing the stored procedure to not work correctly. Why don't you post the whole stored procedure so that we don't go on wild goose chases speculating about the parameters? Why not show exactly how you're calling the stored procedure? Are you sure the stored procedure is in the right database and that you are in the scope of that database? etc. etc.

Comment: Yeah I don't get it.  If I put this code above yours and run, then I get `1` back -- isn't that what you want?  `create table sourceTable (column1 int);declare @column varchar(60);set @column = 'column1'`

Comment: @mr.Reband this is exactly what I want but it's not working for me using the SP :(

Comment: Don't you have to pass the tableName into the procedure, too?  You have `t_table` hard-coded.

Comment: @mr.Reband No I don't as I only need to check one specific table. I saw that I made a mistake in the description and corrected it now. The definition is for the t_table table of course

Comment: So you are just trying to check which columns are in both tables?

Comment: @mr.Reband No, I use the table with the field definition as a template in order to add the columns into the second table at a later step. The problem is that I get error messages if it tries to add a column that is already existing and that's why I need this check

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to venture an answer on this.

I do not recommend using a cursor to go through each column just to test if the column exists in another table.  If you insist on using a cursor, you could use a subquery to limit the results that you're cycling through to only the columns that don't exist in the other table, eliminating the need for the stored procedure that checks each individually (which by the way I think makes more sense as a user function):

```
DECLARE fcursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 't_table' and not column_name in 
(   
    SELECT COLUMN_Name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where table_name = 't_fieldDefinition'
)
```

If your goal really is to alter the table to add any missing columns, then this can be improved by eliminating the cursor and outputting your results using FOR XML:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 
(
    SELECT cast('ALTER TABLE t_fieldDefinition ADD [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] INT;' as varchar(max)) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where table_name = 't_table' and not column_name in 
    (   
        SELECT COLUMN_Name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        where table_name = 't_fieldDefinition'
    ) FOR XML PATH ('')
)
print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. The Problem is that the t_field definition is only a table where I define which fields are imported into the t_table. In reality the fields are part of the table t_sourceTable but I do think that I need to get to this topic a bit different and simply develop a small web interface that is doing this column import for me